# Git version empty

Tags: git, phpstorm-2017.1

I have just had my PC re-built and am trying to re-install PhpStorm and Git. In PhpStorm I have opened the settings panel and navigated to "Version Control > Git". In the "Path to Git executable" field, I have entered the path to Git - C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe.

However, when I click the test button, I get an error saying "Empty git --version output"[image]

The path to Git is correct.

If I open git-bash.exe and type "git --version", I get the correct output - `git version 2.11.0.windows.1`. If I try the same in the windows command prompt, the git bash window flashes open then immediately closes leaving no output in the command prompt.

My Path environment variables contain both C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\ and C:\Program Files\Git\bin.  The PhpStorm version I am running is 2017.1.4

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: check git ssh key configration

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do that. Nothing else I try is working. Thanks